# Using Azure AD for Username/Password SIP sign-in

Tags: adal, skype-for-business, adal.js

I'm developing SIP phone (for Lync environment) and I need to implement ADAL sign-in (SfB online).
I'm trying to use the Azure AD library and its samples to understand how things work. 
The question is which sample fits my needs best. According to specifications the user needs to know only the username and password, this will be enough to get the security token which is used later for SIP TLS-DSK authentication. 
All samples that I've seen use tenant, authUri, clientId. These information pieces my user will not have. Please give me some links ...

Answer (score 0):

The scenarios in which username and passwords can be used directly are extremely limited (details [here](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/08/using-adal-net-to-authenticate-users-via-usernamepassword/)). For devices that are not capable of displaying authentication prompts, please consider [this other approach](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2015/12/02/new-adal-3-x-previewdevice-profile-linux-and-os-x-sample/).